# Resolução tamanho da imagem em Mobile CSS - Aumentar height

Tags: css, html5

To tentando aumenta a imagem de uma div, porem nao to tendo exito.
aqui esta o codigo, estou errando em algo ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
 @media (max-width: 768px){
 
 
  .row-fluid banner cheio{

height:80%;
display:block;
}


    }
```

**Qualquer informação so entra no site informado a baixo e verificar o error**
site : https://www.campifibras.com.br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vitor vc está colocando a altura no lugar errado.

O correto seria colocar direto na imagem. Só que ele vai ficar "deformada" tipo espichada pq vc só vai aumentar a altura e não a largura. Depois vc tem que ver como tratar isso. Ou então pode usar o estilo `object-fit:cover` *(esse estilo faz a imagem se comportar mais ou menos como um `background-image` com `size:cover` )*

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .flexslider .slides img {
        height: 60vh;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

Outra coisa é que o `height` de 80% não vai funcionar porque o elemento em que ele está dentro não tem altura. Então se o Pai não tem altura vc não consegue colocar altura em % no Filho, pois ele não tem um valor de referencia, tipo assim: seria 80% de que altura se ninguém tem altura? Deu para entender?

Nesse caso eu usei o `height` em VH que significa `viewport height`

**OBS:** Se vc preferir pode usar o tamanho fixo em PX também. Ou no próprio @media trocar a imagem quando a tela for menor.